Not able to generate the GRAFANA_API_TOKEN
Not able to generate the GRAFANA_API_TOKEN using 1password tool.
we are planning to use the jsonnet lib to use the Grafana as code. Followed all the steps mentioned in readme file.
while generating the GRAFANA_API_TOKEN it fails with below error
root@CSX-:~/runbooks/dashboards# ./test-dashboard.sh oe/basic-dashboard.jsonnet
/usr/bin/op
[ERROR] 2024/12/02 13:27:41 Output of 'op signin' is meant to be executed by your terminal. Please run 'eval $(op signin)'. You can use the '-f' flag to override this warning.
root@CSX-:~/runbooks/dashboards#

we have already configured op utility and executed op signin and installed all the jsonnet utilities and bundle . however, still the issue.
environment:
OP version: 2.30.3
root@CSX-:~/runbooks/dashboards# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
root@CSX-:~/runbooks/dashboards#

readme url
